# Identity Involving Lie Derivative and Local Flows

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

I'm trying to show,

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t^* \omega = \varphi_t^* \left( \mathcal{L}_{X_t} \omega \right)$$

but I have another question as well. Every case in which the lie derivative is mentioned, that notation $\mathcal{L}_{X_t}$ has never been given interpretation and so I would like to understand this notation first.

Given $\frac{d}{dt}\bigr|_{t=0} \varphi_t = X_p = X_{\varphi_0(p)}$ and so $\frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t = X_{\varphi_t(p)}$ which we can call $X_t$. And so,

$$\mathcal{L}_{X_t} = \mathcal{L}_{\frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t}$$

Is this correct?

Update: [attempt to prove identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd6uZ.jpg)

Comment: When $(\varphi_t)_t$ is the local flow of a time-dependent vector field, then $\varphi_{t+s}\neq\varphi_t\circ\varphi_s$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear but, $\{\varphi_t\}$ are induced by $X \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ and so by ODE theory, we do have this relation.

Comment: Oh, then the identity is really straightforward, see ktoi's answer. However, this is strange to write $X_t$ for a time-independant vector field...

Comment: I updated my "attempt to prove the identity" from some months ago and I came to the understanding that pull-backs commuted with limits. I never checked this off, but you two have helped tremendously and now I can move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The following answer assumes $\varphi_t$ is the associated flow of $X,$ but for a general flow it is incorrect.

**Edit 2**: It seems like OP was asking about this case, in which case my answer would apply.

---

If $\omega$ is some tensor field on $M$ and $X$ is a vector field, the Lie derivative is usually defined as,
$$ \mathcal{L}_X\omega|_p = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \varphi_t^* \omega|_p = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac1t\left(\varphi_t^*(\omega_{\varphi(p)}) - \omega_p \right), $$
where $\varphi_t$ is the associated flow of $X.$

From this, the identity follows essentially by definition, noting you can commute pullbacks with limits. Indeed assuming the flow exists up to some time $t_0,$ we have,

$$\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=t_0} \varphi_t^*\omega = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \varphi_{t_0}^* \varphi_t^*\omega = \left.\varphi_{t_0}^* \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} \varphi_t^*\omega = \varphi_{t_0}^* \mathcal{L}_{X}\omega. $$
I'll leave you to check the details on a pointwise level.

---

Now what I wrote isn't the same as what you asked, since I don't have $X_t$ appearing in my expression. I think this is because of how I interpret the pullback, namely I define,
$$ \varphi^*\omega|_p = \varphi^*|_{\varphi(p)} \omega_{\varphi(p)} \in E_p,$$
where $E$ is whatever bundle $\omega$ is a section of. If you define the pullback differently however, then you may find you'll need to differentiate with respect to $X_t$ when checking the above pointwise.

In general there's nothing special about $X_t = \varphi_{-t}^*X$ however, all you're really doing is shifting the points over so everything lands where they should.

Comment: You are working with time-independent vector fields, while the question is for time-dependent for vector fields. In the latter case, your definition for the Lie derivative is no longer the right one and furtherfore $(\varphi_t)_t$ is no longer a one-parameter subgroup.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I wrote this down some time ago, could you check the edit in my question? Is that the limit thing you are referring to?

Comment: @C.Falcon I think you're right, I assumed $\varphi_t$ was the associated flow of a vector field $X$ but reading the question that doesn't seem to be the case (though it's quite unclear what exactly is being asked). I'll edit my answer noting that.

Comment: @ktoi I'm sorry for the confusion. I made it clear now that $\varphi_t$ were induced from $X$. I apologize, as I've been working in the field for the past few months, I assumed a lot of things when asking my question. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @TopologyGuy I see, in that case your attempt seems fine (it is more or less what I posted after all). Since you tagged this question with the sympletic topology tag however, you may also need the time-dependent version at some point (e.g. to prove the Darboux theorem), so knowing about the general case would also be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I've seen that proof which uses Moser's trick when I read D.Silva. This identity came from McDuff and there's a bit of abuse of notation with that book so I get confused sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove the identity:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}{\varphi_t}^*\omega={\varphi_t}^*(\mathcal{L}_{X_t}\omega),$$

1. Prove that it holds for functions ($0$-forms), it is just the chain rule,
2. Prove that if it holds for $\omega$, then it holds for $\mathrm{d}\omega$, use that the exterior derivative commutes with the pullback and the Lie derivative,
3. Prove that if it holds for $\omega$ and $\omega'$, then it holds for $\omega\wedge\omega'$, use that the pullback of a wedge product is the wedge product of their pullbacks,
4. Conclude using that the algebra of differential forms is locally generated as an algebra by functions and differentials of functions.

Full computations can be found in Appendix B of *An introduction to Contact Topology* by H. Geiges.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm fine with proving the identity that way since you do a similar thing for cartan's homotopy formula $\mathcal{L}_X = d \iota_X + \iota_X d$. I was thinking there was some geometric intuition or "obvious" way to remember the identity, but it seems as though it is one just like the homotopy formula i.e just show that it works for all $k$-forms. Thanks again.

Comment: As a follow up, is my interpretation for $\mathcal{L}_{X_t}$ correct?